# Is possible the same user to have many Team Member Role in the same Account?

Tags: sobject

How can I do it?

P.s: I'm talking about the Sobject AccountTeamMember,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll get a specific error:

> Error: Duplicate Values Not Allowed

A user may only have one single role on the AccountTeamMember object.